# Как брать числовое значение пользовательского поля в битрикс?

Tags: javascript, битрикс

Здравствуйте. Помогите пожалуйста разобраться в особенностях битрикса.

Создала в инфоблоках пользовательское свойство "Размер видимого текста". Это числовое поле, которое позволяет администратору задать размер видимого контента. Сейчас заданы постоянные параметры - если текст карточки превышает 200 px, то он схлапывается до 93 px с возможностью развернуть/свернуть текст. Реализуется при помощи JS. Необходимо, чтобы эти 93px видимого текста были не постоянной величиной, а задаваемые администратором.

Вопрос в том, каким образом брать числовое значение из созданного поля, чтобы оно подставлялось в скрипт? И возможно ли и правильно ли создавать такую переменную внутри скрипта?

Comment: Какой компонент? И свойство у раздела или у элемента?

Comment: Это элемент каталога называется bitrix:catalog.element. Это свойство для элемента - карточка с описанием

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Необходимо просто вывести значение переменной в шаблоне

```
<script>
    var maxHeight = "<?=$arResult["PROPERTIES"][{Код созданного свойства}]["VALUE"]?>";
</script>
```

и после загрузки страницы можно будет использовать его значение

```
<script>
    alert(maxHeight);
</script>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, мне очень помог ваш ответ. Я подставила переменную <?=$arResult["PROPERTIES"][{Код созданного свойства}]["VALUE"]?> , вместо постоянного значения и все работает. Одно уточнение, есть ли там по умолчанию в каких единицах рассчитывается эта видимая зона? Нужно ли дополнительно писать "px"?